# How to fix 'Text not visible in Styled TextBox'

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am Trying to Add Style to a TextBox using xaml but text is not visible. Could Someone Point me to where I could set the foreground to white? Should I be using a Template instead?

I Tried adjusting various elements but with no luck. Style is below

```
<Style x:Key="RoundedTxtBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Grid x:Name="TxtBoxgrid">
                        <Border x:Name="TxtBoxborder" CornerRadius="8" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2">
                            <Border.Background>
                                <RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="0.496,1.052">
                                    <RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                        <TransformGroup>
                                            <ScaleTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" 
                                                    ScaleX="1.5" ScaleY="1.5"/>
                                            <TranslateTransform X="0.02" Y="0.3"/>
                                        </TransformGroup>
                                    </RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                    <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#00000000"/>
                                    <GradientStop Offset="0.3" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
                                </RadialGradientBrush>
                            </Border.Background>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="TxtBoxborder">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="0.496,1.052">
                                        <RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                            <TransformGroup>
                                                <ScaleTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" ScaleX="1.5" ScaleY="1.5"/>
                                                <TranslateTransform X="0.02" Y="0.3"/>
                                            </TransformGroup>
                                        </RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#00000000" Offset="1"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF303030" Offset="0.3"/>
                                    </RadialGradientBrush>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="TxtBoxborder" Value="#FFE6182B"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="TxtBoxgrid" Value="0.25"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

<Button Style="{DynamicResource RoundedTxtBox}" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is your `Style`, but fixed.
It now contains the mandatory parts with their mandatory naming: a content host named *PART_ContentHost*.
You should also bind the template's controls (in this case the `Border` properties) to the appropriate properties of the templated parent (the `TextBox`) using `TemplateBinding`. This enables you to set those values (e.g. `Background` or `BorderThickness`) directly on the `Control`:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
  <Setter Property="Background">
    <Setter.Value>
      <RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="0.496,1.052">
        <RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
          <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" ScaleX="1.5" ScaleY="1.5"/>
            <TranslateTransform X="0.02" Y="0.3"/>
          </TransformGroup>
        </RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
        <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#00000000"/>
        <GradientStop Offset="0.3" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
      </RadialGradientBrush>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
  <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
  <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
  <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
  <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>

      <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
        <Border x:Name="TxtBoxBorder" 
                CornerRadius="8"
                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">

          <!-- The required part with the required name -->
          <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
        </Border>

        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="TxtBoxBorder">
              <Setter.Value>
                <RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="0.496,1.052">
                  <RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                      <ScaleTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" ScaleX="1.5" ScaleY="1.5"/>
                      <TranslateTransform X="0.02" Y="0.3"/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                  </RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                  <GradientStop Color="#00000000" Offset="1"/>
                  <GradientStop Color="#FF303030" Offset="0.3"/>
                </RadialGradientBrush>
              </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
          </Trigger>
          <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="TxtBoxBorder" Value="#FFE6182B"/>
          </Trigger>
          <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="TxtBoxBorder" Value="0.25"/>
          </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

I removed the redundant hosting `Grid` of the `ControlTemplate`. The fewer the elements, the better the performance.

### Remarks

Some controls have mandatory template elements (parts) which must be part of the `ContorlTemplate` and have a special name. When those parts are missing or the name doesn't match the required name, then the functionality of the templated control might get broken. To know the parts and their names of `TextBox` visit [TextBox Parts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/textbox-styles-and-templates#textbox-parts). To know the named parts of all WPF controls visit [Control Styles and Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/control-styles-and-templates). This links also contains an example of the actual default Style and Template.

An alternative approach to get the required template parts is to select the control you wish to template and then open the XAML designer view. Right click on the selected control and select *Edit Template*. In the popup select *Edit a Copy*. A dialog opens. Here you can give the extracted template a name and set the location where the extracted template will be moved to. Now you can edit this template which already has all the required parts.